# Running for loop on results of reactive in shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I want to run a for loop to calculate additional elements in multiple vectors of a dataset, subsetted by a reactive input, in a shiny environment. I have a large dataset with historical data and need to use that data to calculate subsequent elements of data in each vector. I'd like the shiny application to allow a user to select a city to filter the historical dataset, and then the loop will run on that filtered subset. I created a for loop because each vector's element depends on a prior row across 5 different columns, and each calculation depends on a previous calculated element (the calculations need to happen row by row, but across 6 vectors simultaneously). The issue I'm having is that I cannot get the for loop to run successfully in the shiny server.

Here's an example:

This is a mock of the historical dataset structure:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library(shiny)

original <- tibble(id = seq(1:21)) %>%
  mutate(total = 1000,
         mult = 0.75,
         new = c(30:39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
         current = replace_na(ifelse(id <= 4,
                              lag(cumsum(new), 1),
                              lag(rollsumr(new,
                                           k = 4,
                                           fill = NA), 1)),
                              0),
         present = replace_na(ifelse(id <= 2,
                                     lag(cumsum(new), 1),
                                     lag(rollsumr(new,
                                                  k = 2,
                                                  fill = NA), 1)),
                              0),
         gone = replace_na(lag(new, 4),
                           0),
         sum_gone = cumsum(gone),
         subtotal =  total - new - 
                             current -
                             sum_gone,
         model = ifelse(new == 0,
                        "TRUE",
                        "FALSE"),
         city = "Paris")

original2 <- tibble(id = seq(1:21)) %>%
  mutate(total = 2000,
         mult = 0.75,
         new = c(50:59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
         current = replace_na(ifelse(id <= 4,
                                     lag(cumsum(new), 1),
                                     lag(rollsumr(new,
                                                  k = 4,
                                                  fill = NA), 1)),
                              0),
         present = replace_na(ifelse(id <= 2,
                                     lag(cumsum(new), 1),
                                     lag(rollsumr(new,
                                                  k = 2,
                                                  fill = NA), 1)),
                              0),
         gone = replace_na(lag(new, 4),
                           0),
         sum_gone = cumsum(gone),
         subtotal =  total - new - 
           current -
           sum_gone,
         model = ifelse(new == 0,
                        "TRUE",
                        "FALSE"),
         city = "Madrid")

final_original <- rbind(original, original2)
```

Here is an example of the for loop, which works in getting the result I want outside of the shiny environment:

```
##Runs the for loop for the "Paris" data
for (i in original$id) {
  
  if (original$model[i] == FALSE) {
    
    original$new[i] <- original$new[i]
    
    original$current[i] <- original$current[i]
    
    original$present[i] <- original$present[i]
    
    original$gone[i] <- original$gone[i]
    
    original$sum_gone[i] <- original$sum_gone[i]
    
    original$subtotal[i] <- original$subtotal[i]
    
  } else {
    
    original$new[i] <- round(original$mult[i] *
                             original$current[i - 1] *
                             0.5 *
                             original$subtotal[i - 1] / original$total[i])
    
    original$current[i] <- original$current[i - 1] -
                           original$new[i - 5] +
                           original$new[i - 1]
    
    original$present[i] <- original$present[i - 1] -
                           original$new[i - 3] +
                           original$new[i - 1]
    
    original$gone[i] <- original$new[i - 4]
    
    original$sum_gone[i] <- original$sum_gone[i - 1] +
                            original$gone[i]
    
    original$subtotal[i] <- original$total[i] - 
                            original$new[i] - 
                            original$current[i] - 
                            original$sum_gone[i]
    
  }
  
}
```

Conceptually I want the subsetted "historical data" to respond to the reactive input (in this example, the selected city), and then run the for loop. This is what I tried, but I run the table doesn't show and there doesn't seem to be an error message:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    
    column(3,
           
           h4("Select City"),
           
           selectizeInput(inputId = "city",
                          label = "Select City:",
                          choices = c("Paris", "Madrid")
           )
           
    ),
    
    hr(),
    
    tableOutput("sample")
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  actualInput <- reactive({
    
    data <- final_original %>%
      filter(city == input$city)
    
    for (i in data$id) {
      
      if (data$model[i] == FALSE) {
        
        data$new[i] <- data$new[i]
        
        data$current[i] <- data$current[i]
        
        data$present[i] <- data$present[i]
        
        data$gone[i] <- data$gone[i]
        
        data$sum_gone[i] <- data$sum_gone[i]
        
        data$subtotal[i] <- data$subtotal[i]
        
      } else {
        
        data$new[i] <- round(data$mult[i] *
                             data$current[i - 1] *
                             0.5 *
                             data$subtotal[i - 1] / data$total[i])
        
        data$current[i] <- data$current[i - 1] -
                           data$new[i - 5] +
                           data$new[i - 1]
        
        data$present[i] <- data$present[i - 1] -
                           data$new[i - 3] +
                           data$new[i - 1]
        
        data$gone[i] <- data$new[i - 4]
        
        data$sum_gone[i] <- data$sum_gone[i - 1] +
                            data$gone[i]
        
        data$subtotal[i] <- data$total[i] - 
                            data$new[i] - 
                            data$current[i] - 
                            data$sum_gone[i]
        
      }
      
    }
    
  })
  
  output$sample <- renderTable({
    
    actualInput()
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd appreciate any help figuring out how to get the loop to work in the shiny environment, or a different way to get the same outcome from the for loop through a different function.

Comment: At the end of the `actualInput()` reactive expression, you need to "return" something. Try just adding `data` as the last statement of the expression. If it returns `data` when called as `actualInput()` in `renderTable` it should show the `data` in the table as expected.

Comment: This solved it, thank you so much!